# Can I install an NPM package on AWS Lambda without having a local copy/development environment?

Tags: node.js, npm, aws-lambda

I'm using Amazon's web-based code editor to create a simple proof-of-concept, using node.js and Lambda.

I would like to install an NPM package, but I haven't found any way to do this-- if I used the Cloud 9 development environment, I'm able to get a terminal window which allows me to run NPM, but Cloud 9 isn't available in NorCal, where I want to place my code.

Every search that I run instructs me to install node.js on my local machine, create the project, then zip the file and upload it to Lambda.

Is there any way to run NPM without installing node.js locally? Or should I just consider moving to an environment where I can use Cloud 9?

Comment: Do you have access to any CI product?

Comment: I have nothing installed at this point, but that's not to say that I can't. But I'm trying to minimize the number of moving parts as much as possible.

Comment: You could use Github + some CI product to package and deploy your lambda on commit (i.e. using [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com)). That would keep you from installing Node.js in your local environment.